# jQuery clickable element nested in draggable one

Tags: jquery, draggable

Let's say I have got HTML code that looks as follows:

```
<script>
  $("#draggable").draggable();

  $("#clickable").click(function() {
    alert('CLICK!');
  });
</script>

<div id="draggable">
    <div id="clickable">        
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see: clickable div is nested in draggable div. When I drag & drop draggable div using clickable div as handle click event bound to it is fired. That is not desired behaviour. I want the click event to be fired only when you click on clickable but without dragging it anywhere. Is it even possible? I want to add I'm not interested in solutions where setTimeout (or similar) is used. Here you have got jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AJmTg/8/) (note: css is added for better visibility).

Thanks for any clues!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
function handleClick() {
    alert('click!');
};

$("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function () {
        $('#clickable').off('click');
    },
    stop: function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#clickable').on('click', handleClick);
        },1);
    }
});

$("#clickable").on('click', handleClick);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/HmK9z/

Comment: well, I said that setTimeout is not good solution for me ;) but thank you nevertheless

Comment: It's required. You can always ask the UI team to implement a native workaround if you don't want to use it. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

Comment: Probably I will need to use it. I thought there is better workaround to do this.Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback of the draggable method like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable">
    <div id="clickable">        
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var dragged = false;
$("#draggable").draggable({stop:function(ev,ui) { dragged = true;}});

$("#clickable").click(function() {
    if(!dragged)
        alert('CLICK!');
    dragged = false;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AJmTg/9/

Good luck!

Comment: it's not exactly what I want. I don't want click event to be fired at all (of course when clickable is dragged). Nevertheless, thanks :)

Comment: If you don't want the click event to be fired, then why do you bind it to the clickable div?

Comment: to be fired when clicked but not dragged ;)